# find largest most frequent element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, frequency

I have an `ArrayList` in Java with values of

```
4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6
```

and I need to find the most frequent value. If multiple values have the same number of occurrences, return the largest one.

So in the example above, I need to return the value 4.

```
private int getFrequentNumber(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    int popular = arr.get(0);
    int count = 1;
    int tempcount = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        temp = arr.get(i);
        tempcount = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            if(temp == arr.get(j))
                tempcount++;
        }
        if (tempcount > count) {
            popular = temp;
            count = tempcount;
        }
    }
    return popular;
}
```

Right now I have this code so it returns the most frequent number but I need help returning the largest most frequent number.

Comment: I would loop through the input array once, creating an associative array with values of the input array  as key and count as value.
Then search the response in the associative array.

Comment: As a side note, your inner loop must start at 0 and not 1.

Comment: @user6690200 It will result in wrong `count`. Try for `4, 4, 3, 1` Though it returns correct answer, the `count` within that function would be wrong.

Comment: @user6690200 Please see my edited comment.

Comment: @user7 Yes, it will get correct result but the `count` in the method is not correct... It should start from `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step1: QuickSort on `ArrayList<Integer> arr`;

Step2: Iteration on `ArrayList<Integer> arr` as you have done.

Comment: Should not this be a comment instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array store the frequencies of these numbers. After calculating all frequencies, return the largest most frequent number based on this array.

```
private static int getFrequentNumber(ArrayList<Integer> arr){
    int tempcount = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    int[] frequency = new int[arr.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        temp = arr.get(i);
        tempcount = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
            if(temp == arr.get(j))
                tempcount++;
        }
        frequency[i] = tempcount;
    }

    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] >= frequency[maxIndex] && arr.get(i) > arr.get(maxIndex)) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return arr.get(maxIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using a stream on the list, you can group entries on their frequency (counting collector), then find the max frequency. The comparator below is just comparing keys (actual entries) when frequencies are equal (for finding your highest value...

```
List<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 6);

Entry<Integer, Long> maxEntry = arr.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(
                (e1, e2) -> 
                   e1.getValue() == e2.getValue() 
                     ?
                   Long.compare(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey())
                     :
                   Long.compare(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue())  
         )
        .get();

System.out.println(String.format("Most frequent key: %s. Frequency: %s", 
        maxEntry.getKey(), maxEntry.getValue()));
```

The output of this is

```
Most frequent key: 4. Frequency: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward approach uses a map to keep track of frequencies:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
int maxCnt = 0;
int maxNum = 0;

for (int num : arr) {
    int cnt = freq.get(num) == null ? 1 : freq.get(num) + 1;
    if (cnt > maxCnt || (cnt == maxCnt && num > maxNum)) {
        maxCnt = cnt;
        maxNum = num;
    }
    freq.put(num, cnt);
}

if (arr.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("The number " + maxNum + " occurred " + maxCnt + " times.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("There were no numbers available.");
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getPopularElement(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    int count = 1, tempCount;
    int popular = arr.get(0);
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (arr.size()- 1); i++) {
         temp = a.get(i);
         tempCount = 0;
         for (int j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
             if (temp == arr.get(j))
                 tempCount++;
         }
         if (tempCount >= count && temp>popular ) {
             popular = temp;
             count = tempCount;
         }
         if (tempCount > count) {
             popular = temp;
             count = tempCount;
         }
     }
     return popular;
}
```

second way is to sort data as saied by @triffic but it is slower (still in same order i think?)

you should just sort array then all is ok

```
  Collections.sort(arr);
```

your code

```
private int getFrequentNumber(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        Collections.sort(arr);
        int popular = arr.get(0);
        int count = 1;
        int tempCount ;
        int temp ;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            temp = arr.get(i);
            tempCount = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                if (temp == arr.get(j))
                    tempCount++;
            }
            if (tempCount > count) {
                popular = temp;
                count = tempCount;
            }
        }
        return popular;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who don't want to reinvent the bicycle might use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library with [MultiSet](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) collection which holds the elements (integers in our case) and their frequency.

```
    Multiset<Integer> myMultiset = HashMultiset.create(listOfElements);

    // Returns a copy of multiset as an ImmutableMultiset whose iteration order is highest frequency first
    ImmutableMultiset<Integer> integersOrderedByFrequency = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset);
    int intWithHighestFrequency = integersOrderedByFrequency.iterator().next();
    int highestFrequency = myMultiset.count(intWithHighestFrequency);

    // Now we should find the largest Integer among those with the highest frequency
    OptionalInt maxValueOpt = myMultiset.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getCount() == highestFrequency)
            .mapToInt(Multiset.Entry::getElement)
            .max();

    System.out.println(maxValueOpt.getAsInt());
```

Or similar solution:

```
    Multiset<Integer> myMultiset = HashMultiset.create(listOfElements);

    Optional<Integer> result = myMultiset.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((a, b) -> {
                // If count is higher for the first element - rank it higher in the list
                if (a.getCount() > b.getCount()) {
                    return -1;
                // If count is lower for the first element - rank it lower in the list
                } else if (a.getCount() < b.getCount()) {
                    return 1;
                //If element counts are the same - the element with the higher value will be ranked higher
                } else {
                    return b.getElement() - a.getElement();
                }
            })
            .map(Multiset.Entry::getElement)
            .findFirst();

    System.out.println(result.get());
```